# Compact text indication of lost radio connection

Tags: gui-design, interface, labels, text, error-message

I am working on a UI for a robotics application that uses radio communication. There is a text field for each robot that normally displays battery voltage in the format `3.72 V`.

Sometimes the radio communication link breaks, so we can not query the battery voltage.
I want to indicate this to the user place of the battery voltage. I am trying to choose a message of around 5 characters for this purpose.

If the radio connection is lost, most operations with the robot will fail. Our initial design used `N/A` (not applicable / not available) in the field to indicate this, but in my opinion `N/A` connotes more of a "warning" condition than an "error" condition.

Aviation uses `INOP` to indicate subsystems of an aircraft that are inoperative, but this is probably less well-known.

The ideal message would:

- Be a "call to action", telling the user they probably need to fix something
- Indicate that the radio has failed as opposed to a generic "something's wrong"
- Be well-known

Of course I can make the UI more spacious or use icons, but if there is a good short textual message it will be easier to implement.

Comment: NOSIG ?........

Comment: FAIL (4 characters) or ⋆FAIL (5 characters) would seem to indicate failure. Is there a reason why you haven't chosen that?

Answer (score 1):

DOWN it's well known among internet users and somehow indicates that the radio connection is lost.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this better, I'll share 2 possible solutions.

If your users are comfortable with documentation or there is space beside the UI to indicate a legend, you can consider using error codes to describe the error, for example,
Err1 = check battery
Err2 = no signal
...

Otherwise, if your users are power users, they will be familiar with common acronyms, you can consider adapting an acronym, for instance, from this site: https://www.microwavejournal.com/articles/3062-acronyms-and-abbreviations-used-by-the-rf-microwave-industry

Although I tried searching within the link and not sure what to suggest since not enough context is given; you can consider using

```
!-WAN or X-WAN
```

as ! and X are often associated with negative/ not working.

Answer (score 1):

**LOS** ("Loss Of Signal") might be a solution. That is probably what I would use in this case.

> **LOS**
>
> 1. Law of the sea.
> 2. Length of stay.
> 3. Line of scrimmage.
> 4. Line of sight.
> 5. Loss of signal.
>
> <sub>Oxford English Dictionary, via https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/los</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Why no flashing text that alternates between "RADIO" and "LOST"? You can hardly make it clearer and more straightforward.
At the same time, the flashing shows that there is a malfunction that requires user intervention.